# Dynamically created method and decorator, got error 'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__module__'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, functools, endpoints-proto-datastore

I am currently using EndpointsModel to create a RESTful API for all my models on AppEngine. Since it is RESTful, these api have a lot of repeat code which I want to avoid.

For example:

```
class Reducer(EndpointsModel):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)

@endpoints.api(
    name="bigdata",
    version="v1",
    description="""The BigData API""",
    allowed_client_ids=ALLOWED_CLIENT_IDS,
)
class BigDataApi(remote.Service):
    @Reducer.method(
        path="reducer",
        http_method="POST",
        name="reducer.insert",
        user_required=True,
    )
    def ReducerInsert(self, obj):
        pass

    ## and GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
    ## REPEATED for each model
```

I want to make them become generic. So I try to dynamic add method to the class.
What I have tried so far:

```
from functools import partial, wraps

def GenericInsert(self, obj, cls):
    obj.owner = endpoints.get_current_user()
    obj.put()
    return obj

# Ignore GenericDelete, GenericGet, GenericUpdate ...

import types
from functools import partial

def register_rest_api(api_server, endpoint_cls):
    name = endpoint_cls.__name__

    # create list method 
    query_method = types.MethodType(
    endpoint_cls.query_method(
        query_fields=('limit', 'pageToken'),
        path="%ss" % name,
        http_method="GET",
        name="%s.list" % name,
        user_required=True
    )(partial(GenericList, cls=endpoint_cls)))

    setattr(api_server, "%sList", query_method)

    # create insert method
    # ...

register_rest_api(BigDataApi, Reducer)
```

But I got `'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__module__' exception.` 
I think it is because there are some conflicts between `endpoints.method`'s decorator and partial. But no idea how to avoid it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 239, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 298, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 84, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/Users/Sylvia/gcdc2013/apis.py", line 795, in <module>
    register_rest_api(BigDataApi, Reducer)
  File "/Users/Sylvia/gcdc2013/apis.py", line 788, in register_rest_api
    )(partial(GenericList, cls=endpoint_cls)))
  File "/Users/Sylvia/gcdc2013/endpoints_proto_datastore/ndb/model.py", line 1544, in RequestToQueryDecorator
    @functools.wraps(api_method)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/functools.py", line 33, in update_wrapper
    setattr(wrapper, attr, getattr(wrapped, attr))
AttributeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__module__'
```

related articles:

- [Class method differences in Python: bound, unbound and static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114214)
- [Python - can I programmatically decorate class methods from a class instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095616)
- [Programmatically generate methods for a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307602)
- [Adding a Method to an Existing Object Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972)

Comment: This question could be much shorter, by explaining the issue for just `GenericInsert`, for example.

Comment: Without looking too closely, it seems that if you are having naming conflicts then `from functools import partial` -> `import functools` or even `from functools import partial as part` or something might work.

Comment: The essence of the problem is that functools.wraps (being used by the endpoints code, but not in a way that's in any way wrong or unusual) expects the callable being wrapped to have a \_\_module\_\_ attribute (amongst other things). The method you're passing it doesn't have one. http://bugs.python.org/issue3445 suggests this was deemed fix-worthy for python 3.3, but not for 2.7. So you probably just need to do things differently... not much of an answer, sorry.

Comment: @Greg Thanks, the link is very useful to explain the issues

Comment: @Greg. What other ways would you suggest to fix arguments for one function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I also stumbled upon this, I was really surprised, for me the issue was that partial objects are missing certain attributes, specifically `__module__` and `__name__`

Being that `wraps` by default uses `functools.WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS` to update attributes, which defaults to `('__module__', '__name__', '__doc__')` in python 2.7.6 anyway, there are a couple ways of dealing with this ...

Update *only present* attributes ...

```
import functools
import itertools

def wraps_safely(obj, attr_names=functools.WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS):
    return wraps(obj, assigned=itertools.ifilter(functools.partial(hasattr, obj), attr_names))

>>> def foo():
...     """ Ubiquitous foo function ...."""
... 
>>> functools.wraps(partial(foo))(foo)()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/functools.py", line 33, in update_wrapper
setattr(wrapper, attr, getattr(wrapped, attr))
AttributeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__module__'
>>> wraps_safely(partial(foo))(foo)()
>>>
```

Here we simply filter out all those attribute which aren't present.

Another approach would be to **strictly** deal with partial objects only, you could fold `wraps` with `singledispatch` and create wrapped partial objects whose attributes would be taken from the *deepest* `func` attribute.

Something along the lines:

```
import functools

def wraps_partial(wrapper, *args, **kwargs):
    """ Creates a callable object whose attributes will be set from the partials nested func attribute ..."""
    wrapper = wrapper.func
    while isinstance(wrapper, functools.partial):
        wrapper = wrapper.func
    return functools.wraps(wrapper, *args, **kwargs)

def foo():
    """ Foo function.
    :return: None """
    pass

>>> wraps_partial(partial(partial(foo)))(lambda : None).__doc__
' Foo Function, returns None '
>>> wraps_partial(partial(partial(foo)))(lambda : None).__name__
'foo'
>>> wraps_partial(partial(partial(foo)))(lambda : None)()
>>> pfoo = partial(partial(foo))
>>> @wraps_partial(pfoo)
... def not_foo():
...     """ Not Foo function ... """
... 
>>> not_foo.__doc__
' Foo Function, returns None '
>>> not_foo.__name__
'foo'
>>>
```

This is slightly better since now we can get the original functions docs which before defaulted to using the partial objects doc string.

This can be modified to only search if the current partial object doesn't already have the set attribute, which should be slightly faster when nesting many partial objects ...

**UPDATE**

It seems that python(CPython) 3 (at least 3.4.3) doesn't have this issue, since I don't know nor should I assume all versions of python 3 or other implementations such as Jython also share this issue here is another *future ready* approach

```
from functools import wraps, partial, WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS

try:
    wraps(partial(wraps))(wraps)
except AttributeError:
    @wraps(wraps)
    def wraps(obj, attr_names=WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS, wraps=wraps):
        return wraps(obj, assigned=(name for name in attr_names if hasattr(obj, name)))
```

a couple things to note:

- we define a new `wraps` function ***only if we fail to wrap a partial***, in case future versions of python2 or other versions fix this issue.
- we use the original `wraps` to copy the docs and other info
- we don't use `ifilter` since it was removed in python3, I've timeit with and without `ifilter` but the results where inconclusive, at least in python (CPython) 2.7.6, the difference was marginal at best either way...

Answer (score 10):

In Python 3.5 I have found that a reference to the original function is maintained in the `partial`. You can access it as `.func`:

```
from functools import partial

def a(b):
    print(b)


In[20]:  c=partial(a,5)

In[21]:  c.func.__module__
Out[21]: '__main__'

In[22]:  c.func.__name__
Out[22]: 'a'
```

Comment: Also true in Python 2.7.16

Answer (score 2):

If it is the case that it is caused by an issue with "wraps" in functools, there is nothing stopping you from writing your own partial that does not call wraps. According to the python documentation, this is a valid implementation of partial:

```
def partial(func, *args, **keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = keywords.copy()
        newkeywords.update(fkeywords)
        return func(*(args + fargs), **newkeywords)
    newfunc.func = func
    newfunc.args = args
    newfunc.keywords = keywords
    return newfunc
```

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this and thought would mention my workaround for this.

As rightly mentioned by @samy-vilar python3 doesn't have this issue. 
I have some code that uses functools.wrap and needs to run on python2 as well as python3.

For python2 we use [functools32](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/functools32) which is backport of python3's functools for python2. `wraps` implementation of this package works perfect. Additionally it provides lru_cache which is available only in python3 functools.

```
import sys 

if sys.version[0] == '2':
   from functools32 import wraps
else:
   from functools import wraps
```

Answer (score 1):

A pretty convenient solution for python 2.7 is described here: [http://louistiao.me/posts/adding-**name**-and-**doc**-attributes-to-functoolspartial-objects/](http://louistiao.me/posts/adding-__name__-and-__doc__-attributes-to-functoolspartial-objects/)

Namely:

```
from functools import partial, update_wrapper

def wrapped_partial(func, *args, **kwargs):
    partial_func = partial(func, *args, **kwargs)
    update_wrapper(partial_func, func)

    return partial_func
```

Answer (score 0):

In our case I solved this by subclassing functools.partial:

```
class WrappablePartial(functools.partial):

    @property
    def __module__(self):
        return self.func.__module__

    @property
    def __name__(self):
        return "functools.partial({}, *{}, **{})".format(
            self.func.__name__,
            self.args,
            self.keywords
        )

    @property
    def __doc__(self):
        return self.func.__doc__
```

**NB** you could also make use of __getattr__ to redirect queries, but I figured that was actually less readable (and makes it more difficult to insert any useful meta-data as with __name__)