# Dynamic generation of partial functions in Python 2.7.x

Tags: python, embedded, closures, ipython, partial-application

Say I want to dynamically create a function on an IPython shell from the following lambda:

```
f = lambda x, ci: np.percentile(x, 100-ci)
```

that fixes `ci` to a new value. It would be something like the following (`create_new_f` is what I am looking for).

```
ci = 20
new_f = create_new_f(f, ci=ci)
result = new_f([20,30,50,80])
```

I have tried using `functools.partial` as:

```
new_f = functools.partial(f, ci=20)
```

but when I [**run this**](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5935) in an **embedded shell** in IPython I get:

`AttributeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__module__'`

is there any **alternative** way of doing this, perhaps using decorators?

### Background on the topic:

- Here is an IPython [issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5935) that prompted the question.
- Here is a thread [explaining the problem](http://bugs.python.org/issue3445) (and fix in Python 3.x **only**) as well.
- Here is [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594193/dynamic-create-method-and-decorator-got-error-functools-partial-object-has-no) in SO that shows the problem (see the top comment)
- For an even deeper analysis of this problem, see [**this issue**](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/136) in IPython.

again, what I am looking for is an **alternative** way of doing this.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please show a minimal *runnable* example that shows the error you get.

Comment: we don't see create_new_f defined. But see my answer.

Comment: @Bakuriu I have updated the OP to highlight the fact that this is a problem ocurring in embedded shells. I added links to an open `BUG` that shows the problem in IPython as well.

Comment: Instead of using `partial` you can always use a `lambda`. This should solve your problem since `lambda`s *are* real functions.

Comment: @Bakuriu the link to the IPython issue shows that lambdas cannot solve the problem in embedded shells either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Solution for embedded IPython,

You can implement with a closure (I believe this may be your solution):

```
import numpy as np
def partial_f(ci):
    def fn(x):
        return np.percentile(x, 100-ci)
    return fn
new_f = partial_f(20)
new_f([20,30,50,80])
```

returns

```
62.000000000000014
```

---

#### To Check:

`functools.partial` works for me in my IDE's shell at work:

```
import functools
import numpy as np
f = lambda x, ci: np.percentile(x, 100-ci)
ci = 20
new_f = functools.partial(f, ci=ci)
new_f([20,30,50,80])
```

returns

```
62.000000000000014
```

With lambdas (this does work in the [IPython online shell](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/try-ipython/) I tried it out on, but apparently doesn't work for your case):

```
import numpy as np
pf = lambda ci: lambda x: np.percentile(x, 100-ci)
new_f2 = pf(20)
new_f2([20,30,50,80])
```

also returns

```
62.000000000000014
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not work in an IPython embedded shell (see my edits). Any other way of doing this?

Comment: @user815423426 how's that?

Comment: doesn't `partial_f` need to declare `x` as an input argument?

Comment: The last option does not work in embedded shells in IPython either (that was the original solution in the IPython issue)

Comment: The lambda definition does not pick up the definition of `ci` outside of the lambda scope.

Comment: I see, it won't work in the embedded IPython. I'll have to take your word for it.