# Python click: subcommand from partial func

Tags: python, python-click

Say I have a function created not by `def` but by a `partial()` call (or even just by assignment).  In the example below, how can I add `bar` as a click sub-command to the `cli` group?  I can't use the decorator approach (as with `foo`).  My failed approaches are shown below in-line.

```py
import functools
import click


@click.group()
def cli():
    pass


@cli.command()
def foo(myname="foo"):
    print(f"I am {myname}")


bar = functools.partial(foo, myname="bar")

# this has no effect
# cli.command(bar)

# results in: AttributeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute 'name'
# cli.add_command(bar)

# results in: AttributeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute 'hidden'
# cli.add_command(bar, name="bar")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

---

UPDATE: Actually, it looks like the `partial` is the culprit here.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28752007/310441) in a different but related thread, points out that partial objects are "missing certain attributes, specifically `__module__` and `__name__`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing the fact that the `@command` decorator turns the `foo` function into a `Command` that uses the original `foo` as callback. The original function is still accessible as `foo.callback` but `foo` is a `Command`. Still, you can't use a `partial` object as callback because it lacks `__name__`, but you can work around that passing the name explicitly:

```py
bar = functools.partial(foo.callback, myname="bar")
cli.command("bar")(bar)

# Alternative:
cli.add_command(click.Command("bar", callback=bar))
```